# Postgresql Copy update как?

Tags: postgresql

Есть команда copy, которая вставляет данные в таблицы из файла. Есть ли какой-либо аналог не для вставки, а для изменения записи? Можно ли например использовать триггер на insert, в котором будет проверка на существование записи по PK и производить update - как вы думаете насколько это эффективно?

Comment: Я думаю это можно реализовать через `copy to` во временную таблицу и уже из нее сделать изменения через подзапрос `update table t set ... from (subquery for temptable) s where t.... = s....`.

Comment: подойдет ли для этого триггер на временную таблицу? или общий update сработает быстрее

Comment: Не вижу смысла в триггере, зачем он там? Просто перебрасывайте данные из временной таблицы в основную в рамках единой транзакции.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как посоветовали в комментариях сначала сделать `copy` во временную таблицу, а уже потом вставлять в таблицу назначения.

**Первый вариант:**

В PostgreSQL с версии 9.5 у оператора `INSERT` есть необязательное выражение `ON CONFLICT` [документация](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/devel/static/sql-insert.html). Пример:

```
-- создаем временную структуру таблицы назначения копируя 1 строку
CREATE TABLE tmp_tbl AS
(SELECT * FROM tbl LIMIT 1);

-- чистим временную таблицу
TRUNCATE TABLE tmp_tbl;

-- копируем данные из файла
COPY tmp_tbl FROM '/какой-то путь/какой-то файл';

-- вставляем/обновляем данные
INSERT INTO tbl (col1, col2, col3, ...) 
VALUES
    (1, 'asdf', 'sdfds', ...),
    (2, 'cvb'', 'nhfg', ...),
    ...
ON CONFLICT (col1) DO UPDATE 
  SET col2 = EXCLUDED.col2, 
      col3 = EXCLUDED.col3,
     ...;

-- убиваем временную таблицу
DROP TABLE tmp_tbl;
```

**Второй вариант:**

Для версий PostgreSQL младше 9.5. Используем простое обновление и вставку:

```
-- создаем временную структуру таблицы назначения копируя 1 строку
CREATE TABLE tmp_tbl AS
(SELECT * FROM tbl LIMIT 1);

-- чистим временную таблицу
TRUNCATE TABLE tmp_tbl;

-- копируем данные из файла
COPY tmp_tbl FROM '/какой-то путь/какой-то файл';

-- обновляем существующие записи
UPDATE tbl AS t1
SET col2 = t2.col2, 
    col3 = t2.col3,
    ...
FROM tmp_tbl AS t2
WHERE t2.col1 = t1.col1;

-- вставляем новые записи
INSERT INTO tbl (col1, col2, col3, ...)
SELECT t1.col1, t1.col2, t1.col3, ...
FROM tmp_tbl AS t1
LEFT JOIN tbl AS t2 ON t1.col1 = t2.col1
WHERE t2.col1 IS NULL;

-- убиваем временную таблицу
DROP TABLE tmp_tbl;
```

Comment: Есть ли подобное для команды copy?

Comment: У `copy` нет такого функционала. Сначала скопируйте во временную таблицу, а потом уже вставляйте в основную.

Comment: Расширил ответ и добавил второй вариант решения для младших версий.

Comment: Спасибо, второй вариант решил бы так: INSERT INTO ....
EXCEPTION WHEN unique_violation THEN
    UPDATE ...